# Различие между Intent и PendingIntent

Tags: android, android-intent

Кто нибудь может внятно обьяснить, что это за сущность - PendingIntent?

В каких случаях применять? И в чем ее отличие от обычного Intent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вся разница заключается в правах доступа к твоему приложению.

PendingIntent - обертка, которая позволяет стороннему приложению выполнять определенный код (твоего приложения) с правами которые определены для твоего же приложения.

Если в стороннее приложение передать простой Intent то он будет выполняться с правами которые имеет само приложения.

Советую взглянуть на примеры взаимодействия с другими приложениями (будильник, календарь и тд). Вот нашел небольшой - http://android-helper.com.ua/alarm/

Comment: Сайт с примерами помер.

Comment: Но в архиве он все еще есть https://web.archive.org/web/20161123233908/http://android-helper.com.ua/alarm/

Answer (score 11):

PendingIntent позволяет стороннему приложению (в которое его передали) запустить хранящийся внутри него Intent, от имени того приложения (и теми же с полномочиями ) передавшего этот PendingIntent.

А Intent работает внутри приложения.

Comment: Intent можно передавать во внешние приложения.